# Object do not have a fields that have been set into the overriden operator new without define constructor into the derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, new-operator

I have a problem with undersending how work override operator new. I have the base class Task with a overridden operator new:

```
void* operator new(size_t bytes, const allocate_continuation_proxy& p);
```

This operator is used for allocate a new task and set private fields from current working task. allocate_continuation_proxy& is refer to current task.

```
class allocate_continuation_proxy; 

class Task { 
public: 
    virtual ~Task() { 
    } 

    void* operator new(size_t size) { 
        return ::operator new(size); 
    } 

    void* operator new(size_t bytes, const allocate_continuation_proxy& p); 

    allocate_continuation_proxy& allocate_continuation() { 
        return *reinterpret_cast<allocate_continuation_proxy*>(this); 
    } 

    virtual Task* Compute() = 0; 

    inline Task* Continuation() { 
        return _continuation; 
    } 

    inline void Continuation(Task& task) { 
        _continuation = &task; 
    } 

    inline void ContinuationAsNull() { 
        _continuation = nullptr; 
    } 

protected: 
    Task() { 
    } 

private: 
    Task* _continuation; 
    Ct* _cancellationToken; 
}; 

class allocate_continuation_proxy { 
public: 
    Task& allocate(size_t size) const; 
}; 

inline Task& allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(size_t size) const { 
    Task& t = *((Task*)this); 
    Task* c = (Task*) ::operator new(size); 
    c->CancellationToken(nullptr); 
    c->Continuation(*t.Continuation()); 
    c->PendingCount(0); 
    t.ContinuationAsNull(); 
    return *c; 
} 

inline void* Task::operator new(size_t bytes, const allocate_continuation_proxy& p) { 
    return &p.allocate(bytes); 
}
```

I try to execute this code:

```
class C0 : public Task { 
public: 
    //C0() { 
    //} 

    Task* Compute() override { 
        std::cout « "C0 is computing..." « std::endl; 
        Task* c = Continuation() 
        c->Compute(); //if constuctor C0() is not been to define, this line throw exception because "c" = nullptr, but "c" has to point on instance of C2
        return nullptr; 
    } 
}; 

class C2 : public Task { 
public: 
    Task* Compute() override { 
        std::cout « "C2 is computing..." « std::endl; 
        return nullptr; 
    } 
}; 

class C1 : public Parallel::Task { 
public: 
    Task* Compute() override { 
        std::cout « "C1 is computing..." « std::endl; 
        C0& c = *new (allocate_continuation()) C0(); 
        c.Compute(); 
        return nullptr; 
    } 
}; 

int main() { 
    C1& c1 = *new C1(); 
    c1.Continuation(*new C2()); 
    c1.Compute(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

My problem is into the this line:

```
C0& c = *new (allocate_continuation()) C0();
```

If constuctor C0() is not been to define, refer "c" does not have _continuation that has been set into the allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(size_t size). But If I define a constructor into the class C0, refer "c" will have a _continuation. I don`t understand why? And How can I get the correct behavior without defining a constructor into the derived class?

Comment: `operator new` is for allocating memory. Constructors are for constructing an object. Mixing them up is a recipe for failure.

Comment: I know it, but I look at Intel Threading Building Blocks library and they do the same thing. I want understand how it work, because when I tried to do this I`ve got a problem that I discribed.

Comment: Example from tbb: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler/catalog_of_recommended_task_patterns.html

Comment: OK I see. Don't understand what's your problem though. Are you getting any compilation errors?

Comment: No, I have a runtime exception. Look at class C0. Behaiver depends on constructor exist or does not.

Comment: In your allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate: `Task& t = *((Task*)this);` this doesn't make any sense to me. `this` is an `allocate_continuation_proxy`, not a `Task`, nothing good will come after that.

Comment: @Juliano  he casts `Task` to `allocate_continuation_proxy` in `allocate_continuation_proxy& allocate_continuation()`. It's very weird, but seems well-defined.

Comment: You can not do these reinterpret cast, especialy with classes that have virtual functions! Usualy, we make the class task inherits the allocator class: this way if your allocator is an empty class, you'll get no memory overhead due to empty base class optimization (conformant compilers folows this rule, I believe only pre vc15 does not follow it). Then, in `allocate()`, replace the first line by `static_cast<Task*>(this)`. This will bring you back to defined behavior.

Comment: @krzaq It's utterly undefined to call a nonstatic member function of class X on a not-an-X object.

Comment: I cannot compile your code, there are too many things left undefined.

Comment: @Juliano There are no actual allocate_continuation_proxy objects there. The type is a dispatch tag. The way this code is supposed to work is casting a `Task*` to `allocate_continuation_proxy*`, dispatching to the right `operator new`, and then casting back to `Task*`.